# The absolute URL for google endpoints

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm unable to find the absolute URL for the REST endpoints created by google appengine endpoints sample.

The configuration of the web.xml and MyEndpoints seems to be

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/myApi/v1/sayHi/sam
```

but this gives an

> ERROR 404

what is the endpoint which can be tested locally

Comment: can you please try to replace .../api/... with .../spi/...

Comment: have a look at your app.yaml file

Comment: I don't have the file app.yaml in my project

Comment: Can you post your discovery doc? `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/myApi/v1/rest`. If this 404s, go to `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis` and post what is there.